# Permanent hostname change on Ubuntu

Tags: 16.04, startup, hostname

I have successfully changed the hostname of my Ubuntu machine, though whenever I restart it, I need to run this command to access it using host name

```
sudo /etc/init.d/hostname.sh start
```

This is what I used to do the change:

```
# take care of "hostname" command and editing "/etc/hostname"
hostnamectl set-hostname <new.hostname>
# Edit "/etc/hosts"
127.0.1.1     <new.hostname>
```

How can I make this permanent?

Comment: You could simply add that line to your sudo crontab.

Comment: Yeah, I could do that. I was wondering if there was a "right" way to persist this setting. Thanks.

Comment: Well, it should already *be* persistent.  Now the question is why your system is not setting the hostname from `/etc/hostname` at boot without manually (re-)running `hostname.sh`.

Comment: That's what I am wondering :)

Comment: After running the `hostnamectl` command, have you checked what the contents of `/etc/hostname` are?

Comment: yes. `/etc/hostname` is correct.

Comment: To add that command to your startup, you would need to edit the `/etc/crontab` file and add at the bottom `@reboot root /etc/init.d/hostname.sh start` that way every time it starts up it will run that command.

Answer (score 5):

I followed [these instructions] and it worked even after restart the machine.

Summary:

```
sudo hostname NEW_NAME_HERE
sudo nano /etc/hostname # change OLD_NAME by NEW_NAME
sudo nano /etc/hosts # change OLD_NAME by NEW_NAME
sudo systemctl restart systemd-logind.service
hostnamectl set-hostname NEW_NAME_HERE
```

Also you should recreate your ssh keys on your machine:

```
sudo rm /etc/ssh/ssh_host_*
sudo dpkg-reconfigure openssh-server
```

Just in case, check references of your old hostname on /etc and fix it:

```
sudo grep -R OLD_NAME /etc/ 2>/dev/null
```

Comment: I've always used the first 3 commands, but the `grep` was helpful - I found the OLD_NAME in `/etc/mailname` and `/etc/exim4/update-exim4.conf.conf`.

Answer (score 3):

Edit the file `/etc/hostname`.

From [`man 5 hostname`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/hostname.5.html):

> It should contain a single newline-terminated hostname string.

Comment: I've already done that. Added details to the question.

Comment: As I have mentioned in the question, the `hostnamectl set-hostname` takes care of that. Here: http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man1/hostnamectl.1.html

Comment: Which version of ubuntu are you running?  Is the initialization via `systemd` or `init` ?

Comment: Good point. 16.04. Updated question. Not sure I know how to check how the system is being initialized.

Comment: Do you have a symlink `/etc/rcS.d/S02hostname.sh -> ../init.d/hostname.sh` ?  (or similar)

Comment: yes indeed, I do have that link.